# Is it possible to add a certain javascript to a new html page in framework7?

Tags: javascript, html, html-framework-7

I'm new to framework7 and i'm creating a new page in my framework7 app. I want to be able to add a certain javascript code like this `<script type="text/javascript" src="sample.js"></script>` into a new page html file using framework7 . For example this is my new page which consists of just a "try" button.

```
<template>

    <div class="page">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="title">{{title}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="page-content">
                    <button class="sample">try</button>
                </div>
            </div>

</template>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Exp.js"></script>
```

So in the new page as you can see I've added `<script type="text/javascript" src="Exp.js"></script>` which is a javascript file named Exp.js which looks like this

```
\\ "try" button event listener
document.querySelector('.sample').addEventListener("click", function () {
alert(works);
});
```

So what it does is Whenever i click the "try" button in the page , it should alert "works", but this does not work.

Is there any way that i can add javascript files like this? or is not possible in framework7 to add javascript files like that? please do help me with an answer

And this is my framework7 app initialize js file.

```
var myApp = new Framework7({
    // App root element
    root: '#app',
    // App Name
    name: 'My App',
    // App id
    id: 'com.myapp.test',

    // Enable swipe panel
    panel: {
        swipe: 'left',
    },
    // Add default routes
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/about/',
            url: 'about.html',
        },
        {
            path: '/Expenses/',
            componentUrl: 'Expenses.html',
        },
    ],

    // ... other parameters
});

// Add view
var mainView = myApp.views.create('.view-main', {
    // Because we want to use dynamic navbar, we need to enable it for this view:
    stackPages: true,
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, your question is now clearer. See the component page below for the **Expense.html** file. This is the "more official" way of doing things in Framework7. It may be a little new, depending on what your javascript background is. You have a component file that has the html template, javascript functions and data.

The script part is where you define data and methods to be used in your component page. I have created a function called *alertWorks* which basically does what you were trying to do. Then I have called that function using the "@click" notation on the button. This is how I have added my event handler to the click event of the button. I have also gone a little step further to create some data for the *title* variable that you used at the top of the page. This is just basic bare bones, but should help to introduce you to F7.

```
<template>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="title">{{title}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page-content">
      <button class="sample" @click="alertWorks">try 1</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  return {
    data: function () {
      return {title: "Button Page"};
    },
    methods: {
      alertWorks(e) {
        alert('works');
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

And then your router would look something like this

```
routes: [
    {
        path: '/about/',
        url: 'about.html',
    },
    {
        path: '/Expenses/',
        componentUrl: 'Expenses.html',
    },
],
```

See the [docs explanation](http://framework7.io/docs/router-component.html#single-file-component) here.

Comment: What you told works fine, but this is not what i actually wanted. I've edited my question and made the question more understandable. Please do re-check and provide me with an answer if you do know :)

Comment: I have edited the answer to solve the edited question.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. This was a little new to me, because i'm very new to framework7.

Comment: Yeah. The first versions of Framework7 were more friendly to jQuery developers. The more recent ones have more "new" stuff. But it will flow pretty smoothly once you get the hang of it :)

Comment: Thank you @Stone10 for explanation, Framework7 documentation is vague and uncertain for F7 beginners, although some information in chaotic order is thrown there. Particularly useful was your direct link into F7 docs. I asked this question both to chatGPT and Bing-powered-by-GPT and they didn't know. Sure, there is no similar information on F7 forum. How did you learned this?